# Java ternary (inline) operators: accesing comparation variables

Tags: java, variables, conditional-operator

In Java, i have an expression like the following:

```
return (a.getValue() > b.getValue()) ? a.getValue() : b.getValue();
```

When I was about 13 years old, i used to code in MSL (mIRC Scriptint Language).
That language had the following ternary operator:

```
return iif($valueOfA > $valueOfB, $v1, $v2);
```

where $v1 and $v2 represent $valueOfA and $valueOfB.

I don't like it that i have to call `a.getValue()` and `b.getValue()` twice, and also this is very ugly (and breaks the point of the **inline** operator):

```
valA = a.getValue();
valB = b.getValue();
return (valA > valB ? valA : valB);
```

So i'm looking for something like this:

```
return (a.getValue() > b.getValue) ? [param1] : [param2];
```

Comment: Here you could just get away with `Math.max`. But seriously: in Java one has to rely on the (hotspot) compiler. So it helps to make the methods final. Another language: `let av = a.getValue(), bv = b.getValue() in av > bv ? av : bv`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like :

```
return ((a.getValue() > b.getValue()) ? a : b)).getValue();
```

Could already helps. You could also implement some method in A & B classes to compare a "A" and a "B" directly, to be able to write something like :

```
return ((a.greaterThan(b)) ? a : b).getValue(); // no operator overload in Java
```

Also, if you are using objects, maybe returning a or b (and not their "value") would be a better idea.

This depends of course of the classes and usages you make of "a" and "b".

Comment: Just a note that unless you got 2nd approach implemented you are still calling `getValue()` twice and `return ((a.getValue() > b.getValue()) ? a : b)).getValue();` is basically the same as `return (a.getValue() > b.getValue()) ? a.getValue() : b.getValue();` - it just **looks** differently.

Answer (score 2):

> So i'm looking for something like this:
>   return (a.getValue() > b.getValue) ? [param1] : [param2];

Java language is clearly defined. Looking for non existing feature is futile. Or to make things simple "no".

And as a comment, this:

```
iif($valueOfA > $valueOfB, $v1, $v2);
```

is not **operator**. It can be macro, function, method but not operator.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing this?

```
int x, y;
int result =((x = a.getValue()) > (y = b.getValue())? x: y);
```

The above example:

1. Creates two integer variables (or whatever type you like).
2. In the ternary operation assigns a.getValue() to x and b.getValue() to y.
3. Performs the test and returns the variable according to the condition.